# Rotating pages in Evince document viewer

Tags: pdf, evince, rotate

I'm putting this as a quick question and answer as it surprises me it's not answered here:

Opening a document using the default document viewer in 22.04LTS (Evince) but the document is malrotated - how to rotate it 90 or 180 degrees clockwise or counter-clockwise quickly? The drop-down menu only gives the option to rotate 90 degrees clockwise - is there a quick keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> (left arrow) will rotate 90 degrees left

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> (right arrow) will rotate 90 degrees right

This is obviously not saving the rotated image (which is answered elsewhere) but rotates how it's displayed.

Source: https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/shortcuts.html.en